# Subfigures set in grid

Tags: subfloats

I am struggling to place a series of subfigures in a 2x3 gri

Apologies, I can see similar questions to this have been asked before, and I have attempted to try what is suggested but the responses seem very specific to the individual use case. I would also appreciate any comments people have that can aid my understanding of the issue, in addition to a solution to the problem.

[image: subfigure example]

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\graphicspath{{figures/dig_simulations/}}
\begin{figure}  
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \caption{Tversky \& Kahneman}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{TK_1.png}               
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \caption{Lattimore}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Lattimore_1.png}    
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
            \caption{Lattimore}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Lattimore_2.png}            
    \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
            \caption{Lattimore}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Lattimore_3.png}    
    \end{subfigure}
    \medskip
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \centering
        \caption{Prelec}
            \includegraphics[width=2in]{Prelec_1.png}       
    \end{subfigure}
            \caption{Prelec}%\label{fig:2b}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \centering
                \caption{Prelec}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Prelec_2.png}               
    \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Prelec_3.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{example caption}   
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code I have commented out some lines of your original example and added four lines (highlighted by `<-----`):

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\graphicspath{{figures/dig_simulations/}}
\begin{figure}  
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \caption{Tversky \& Kahneman}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{TK_1.png}               
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \caption{Lattimore}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Lattimore_1.png}    
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
            \caption{Lattimore}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Lattimore_2.png}            
    \end{subfigure}

 \medskip  % <-------------------------------  
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
            \caption{Lattimore}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Lattimore_3.png}    
    \end{subfigure}
%    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \centering
        \caption{Prelec}
            \includegraphics[width=2in]{Prelec_1.png}       
    \end{subfigure}
%            \caption{Prelec}%\label{fig:2b}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \centering
                \caption{Prelec}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Prelec_2.png}               
    \end{subfigure}
%        \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
%        \end{subfigure}

\medskip % <-------------------------------
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{2in}
        \centering
        \caption{test}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{Prelec_3.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{example caption}   
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]